# Cannot find octokit gem when running ruby, but irb can find it

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I ran `rvm implode` to get a fresh install, then reinstalled RVM and ruby. Then I installed the octokit gem which I want to run.

When I run `require 'octokit'` in `irb` everything works, but when I try it from the command line, like such:

`ruby file.rb` where file.rb is:

```
require 'octokit.rb'
require 'csv.rb'
CSV.open("node_attributes.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << [Octokit.user "dbussink"]
  csv << [Octokit.user "sferik"]
end
```

I get:

`1:in require: no such file to load -- /octokit (LoadError)`

`which ruby` yields `/usr/bin/ruby`, `which irb` yields `/usr/bin/irb`, but `which octokit` yields `octokit not found`.

Further, `rvm list` yields:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

And, `gem list octokit` yields:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

octokit (1.25.0, 1.4.0)
```

How can I make sure that I can find `octokit` when running `ruby` from the command line? I've tried changing the path, using an explicit path in the require command, etc., but nothing seems to work!

Comment: If you are indeed using `rvm` your ruby path should not look like `/usr/bin/ruby` - are you sure rvm is configured properly?  Try running `rvm list` and `rvm use 1.9.3` (or `2.0`)

Comment: I added the output of `rvm list` to the question, thanks.

Comment: updated to show `gem list octokit`, thanks.

Comment: And `which ruby` still points to `/usr/bin/ruby` even in a new console?

Comment: Yup, every time I open a new console, it still points to `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: Hum, this sounds like an RVM configuration issue.  You might want to try reinstalling RVM...

Comment: RVM is newly installed. I imploded it and installed it again. 2x.

Comment: In your statement: *When I run require 'octokit' in irb everything works, but when I try it from the command line...*, what do you mean by "try it from the command line"? Do you mean you're running a ruby script file from the command line? If so, could you show the first few lines of that script?

Comment: Question updated to show how I run the .rb file

Comment: Did you ensure that you added RVM to your path?

Comment: So that would be the path specified in `which rvm`?

Comment: `which rvm` yields `/Users/histelheim/.rvm/bin/rvm` which is in the path. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `require 'octokit'` *not require 'octokit.rb'*. I see why you'd require the latter (name of the project on GitHub).